# Getting objects from xml response

Tags: java, xml, json, parsing, jaxb

In my server code, I receive an `XML` response. I need to modify that `XML` response and send it to the client either in `XML` or in `JSON`. I know it can be achieved by parsing the `XML` and removing some tags and so on. But I need to do it without parsing. How can I use `JAXB` to achieve the result? Any other solution without `JAXB` is also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  [XSLT](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2004k/ctl257/JavaXSLT/Ch05.html) to transform one form of XML to other.

Comment: My problem is to modify the existing xml a bit and covert the rest into json format. Could you please give some details on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The MOXy implementation of JAXB allows you to apply multiple mappings to your domain model.  One can be done through annotations, and multiple can be done using the external binding document.  In the example below I map one object model to different XML documents representing weather information from both Google and Yahoo:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Answer (score 0):

[JAXP](http://jaxp.java.net/) might be a better option in this case if you need to transform the XML.